# Moveit! move_group segmentation fault on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 with Raspberry Pi 3 (ROS kinetic)

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, raspberrypi, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am currently trying to run ROS kinetic with Moveit! on my Raspberry Pi 3 board.

I successfully installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 (https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/), ROS kinetic (http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) and Moveit! packages on the Raspberry.

I also successfully built all the packages for my custom robot with catkin. And I can launch my nodes, set robot_description param, etc... The problems comes when I launch move_group (with move_group.launch from my moveit config folder)

Note that everything is working fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop installation, I created and tested all my packages. Here is what is happening on my laptop, while running "roslaunch my_robot_package_moveit_config move_group.launch"  :

```
...
...
[ INFO] [1482395047.420033154]: Loading robot model 'my_robot'...
[ INFO] [1482395047.511544563]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[New Thread 0x7fffcbdf8700 (LWP 5206)]
...
...
```

However, on the Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu Mate, with the **exact same installation, config and files** :

```
NODES
  /
    move_group (moveit_ros_move_group/move_group)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[move_group-1]: started with pid [17610]
[ INFO] [1482398385.724625628]: Loading robot model 'my_robot'...
[ INFO] [1482398386.383339632]: Loading robot model 'my_robot'...
[move_group-1] process has died [pid 17610, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group __name:=move_group __log:=/home/niryo/.ros/log/d73c13fc-c826-11e6-b1b9-b827eb50f10b/move_group-1.log].
log file: /home/my_robot/.ros/log/d73c13fc-c826-11e6-b1b9-b827eb50f10b/move_group-1*.log
```

I also launched move_group.launch with debug:=true :

```
...
... 
[ INFO] [1482398405.376777619]: Loading robot model 'my_robot'...

Thread 1 "move_group" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76f73f96 in std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_emplace_hint_unique<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) ()
   from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libmoveit_planning_scene_monitor.so.0.9.3
...
...
```

I also tried with Ubuntu ARM (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) and I got the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix that ? Is it a Raspberry Pi relative problem ? Or Ubuntu version problem ? Or a Moveit! problem ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250606/moveit!-move_group-segmentation-fault-on-ubuntu-mate-16.04-with-raspberry-pi-3-(ros-kinetic)/) by [renarded](https://answers.ros.org/users/28606/renarded/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2017-01-11**:
Apologies for a question unrelated to yours, but I'm a ROS beginner. Based on your ROS/Pi experience:
For a new project, I can get a Pi 3, or wait until Feb 29, when the Pi 4 may (or may not) come out. Some speculate there will be no update this year. Is a Pi 3 sufficient for ROS, or should I wait?

**Comment by [renarded](https://answers.ros.org/users/28606/renarded/) on 2017-01-11**:
@tommytwoeyes I've heard that there will be no Pi 4 for 2017, but many improvement on OSes around RPI3. RPI3 is powerful enough for most ROS applications, so I think you'd better start with Pi3 now.

**Comment by [roser](https://answers.ros.org/users/30166/roser/) on 2017-04-26**:
Hey, I'm facing the same issue. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally solved my problem :

I had to remove all geometry stuff from my URDF file :  visual and collision, including box, cylinder and meshes. That way move_group is not having this segfault and everything is running.

So I'm guessing I am missing some dependencies or packages on my Raspberry Pi 3 with armhf (reminder : everything works well on my 64 bit laptop and on my 32 bit laptop).

---

Note : this is only a partial answer, as now I have another problem : collisions will not be detected because I removed them from the URDF.

---

Originally posted by [renarded](https://answers.ros.org/users/28606/renarded/) with karma: 161 on 2017-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-01-12**:
This is not an answer at all.. As you stated collision testing doesn't work if you remove the collision bodies. :)

I know there have been problems with the binary package of FCL on non-x86 platforms in the past. Maybe this is still a problem?
You could try to build FCL from source.

**Comment by [renarded](https://answers.ros.org/users/28606/renarded/) on 2017-01-17**:
@v4hn thanks for your advice, I will try that when I have time and will let you know about the result